# chainerにおける勾配情報の取得方法について

Tags: python, chainer

chainerに関する質問です。

学習済みのNNモデルをロードし、ある画像を入力した際の各層の勾配情報を取得したいのですが、実装できずに悩んでいます。

ネットワークは以下のように定義しています。

```
class Model1(chainer.Chain):

    def __init__(self, input_chs, n_outputs):

        super(Model1Activation, self).__init__()

        with self.init_scope():

            self.I = []
            self.conv1 = L.Convolution2D(input_chs, 16, 5, stride=1, pad=0)
            self.conv1_hidden = []
            self.relu1_hidden = []
            self.maxpool1_hidden = []
            self.conv2 = L.Convolution2D(16, 32, 5, stride=1, pad=0)
            self.conv2_hidden = []
            self.relu2_hidden = []
            self.maxpool2_hidden = []
            self.conv3 = L.Convolution2D(32, 64, 5, stride=1, pad=0)
            self.conv3_hidden = []
            self.relu3_hidden = []
            self.l4 = L.Linear(1*1*64, 100)
            self.l4_hidden = []
            self.l5 = L.Linear(100, n_outputs, nobias=True)
            self.pred = []

    def __call__(self, X):

        # -> Input
        self.I = Variable(X)

        # -> 14*14*16
        self.conv1_hidden = self.conv1(self.I)
        self.relu1_hidden = F.relu(self.conv1_hidden)
        self.maxpool1_hidden = F.max_pooling_2d(self.relu1_hidden, 2)

        # -> 5*5*32
        self.conv2_hidden = self.conv2(self.maxpool1_hidden)
        self.relu2_hidden = F.relu(self.conv2_hidden)
        self.maxpool2_hidden = F.max_pooling_2d(self.relu2_hidden, 2)

        # -> 1*1*64
        self.conv3_hidden = self.conv3(self.maxpool2_hidden)
        self.relu3_hidden = F.relu(self.conv3_hidden)

        # -> 100
        self.l4_hidden = self.l4(self.relu3_hidden)
        self.relu4_hidden = F.relu(self.l4_hidden)

        # -> n_outputs
        self.pred = self.l5(self.relu4_hidden)

        return self.pred
```

mainの中でモデルを読み込み、以下のようにして勾配情報を取り出そうとするとNoneと表示されてしまいます。

```
main():

    #中略
    #(modelという変数にModel1モデルを読み込み、画像を入力した際のロスをlossに格納)

    loss.backward(retain_grad=True)
    print(model.I.grad)
```

クラスとして定義したモデルにはgradが保存されないのか、そうであるなら各層の勾配情報を取得するにはどのように記述したらよいかを教えていただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

短く言えば，[chainer.grad](https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/chainer.grad.html)を利用してください．(使用例はExample 3を参照ください．)
以下は詳細です．

Q71.MSK氏の回答は誤っています．まず，通常，Variable.backward()後に，入力の勾配を取得することはできます．

Example 1

```
import chainer
from chainer import Variable
from chainer import functions as F

import numpy as np


inp = Variable(np.array([1., 2., 3.]))
intermediate = inp * 3
out = F.sum(intermediate)

out.backward()

print(inp.grad)
```

Output 1

```
[3. 3. 3.]
```

このように，入力値の勾配を取ることはできます．
しかし，質問の通り，中間特徴の勾配を取ることはできません．

Example 2

```
import chainer
from chainer import Variable
from chainer import functions as F

import numpy as np


inp = Variable(np.array([1., 2., 3.]))
intermediate = inp * 3
out = F.sum(intermediate)

out.backward()

print(intermediate.grad)
```

Output 2

```
None
```

これは，計算グラフの効率化と呼ばれる仕様で，GPUメモリの省略のために，Variable.backward()は葉ノード以外の全てのgradを記憶しません．
そこで，正しいコードは以下のようになります．

Example 3

```
import chainer
from chainer import Variable
from chainer import functions as F

import numpy as np


inp = Variable(np.array([1., 2., 3.]))
intermediate = inp * 3
out = F.sum(intermediate)

intermediate_grad = chainer.grad((out,), (intermediate,))[0]
print(intermediate_grad)
```

Output 3

```
variable([1. 1. 1.])
```

Comment: Q71.MSKさんへ
StackOverflowの信用度が足りないため，コメントに返信できないので別に質問を建てていただけると，回答出来るかと思います．

短く言えば，私の環境(Chainer==v5.0.0b3)では，L.Linearを噛ませても，F.softmaxを噛ませても，retain_grad==Trueを指定すると，きちんと中間のgradientは計算されます．

Answer (score 0):

すみません、間違えていました。質問者さんは「入力値」の勾配を取りたい、と。私の理解では、勾配は、値を変更する、学習するために計算をするものです。では、「入力値」は、学習するのでしょうか。当然しないので、勾配は計算されない、と思うのですが、いかがでしょうか。

では2つめ、任意の層の勾配ですが、すでにとれているのではないでしょうか。_hidden ポストフィックスの変数の grad に入っているはずです。
なお、

```
 y = relu(conv2d(y))
 y = relu(conv2d(y))
 return y
```

の様に、計算結果を残さない場合、最後の出力から creator.inputs を調べることで以前の結果に上っていけます。この場合、[Chainer v3 で勾配が計算されない件](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chainer-jp/2HDDM3yQskY) で報告されているように、「Chainer V3以降」「Linear など（未詳）の関数を使う」の2つの条件を満たすと、勾配の計算結果が残りません。これは [issue 4220](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/issues/4220) に登録されています。回避策として、質問者さんのように、計算結果をどこかに参照させておきます。

Comment: 他の方へコメントがつけられないのでここで。
実際に動作させているコードでの現象を元に回答しておりますので、失礼ながら、検証いたしました。
検証環境は、Chainer 4.1.0 で、CPU のみ使用しています。実際に動作しているネットワークでは、Convolution2D, ReLU, BatchNormalization, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Linear, Softmax を使用しています。
Example 1... 示されているコードでは、勾配は計算されました。しかし、動作中のコードでは None でした。

Comment: Example 2... 示されているコードでは None が表示されますが、backward に引数として「retain_grad=True」を指定することで、「[1. 1. 1.]」が表示されます。質問者さんのコードでも retain_grad=True が指定されています。メモリ省略の為に grad を記憶しないことは承知しております。そこを保持するように指定するのが retain_grad=True だと思います。質問者さんのコードで、retain_grad=True を指定しても保持されていないのはなぜでしょうか。
「Chainer v3 で勾配が計算されない件」で報告し、PFNの大野氏に確認していただいているとおり、「Linear, Softmax を追加すると、勾配の計算結果が残りません」。質問者さんも Linear を使用されています。これが関係していないでしょうか。
Example 3... ありがとうございます。backward に時間がかかっていましたが、かなり短縮できました。しかし、動作中のコードでは grad_outputs オプション引数に勾配の初期値を指定する必要がありました。

Answer (score 0):

For Q71.MSK氏
別トピックを建てていただけると良かったのですが，それを待つのも面倒なので，ここでご回答いたします．

Example 4

```
from chainer import Chain, Variable
from chainer import functions as F
from chainer import links as L

import numpy as np


class Model1(Chain):
    def __init__(self, input_chs, n_outputs):
        super().__init__()
        with self.init_scope():
            self.conv1 = L.Convolution2D(input_chs, 16, 5, stride=1, pad=0)
            self.conv2 = L.Convolution2D(16, 32, 5, stride=1, pad=0)
            self.conv3 = L.Convolution2D(32, 64, 5, stride=1, pad=0)
            self.l4 = L.Linear(1 * 1 * 64, 100)
            self.l5 = L.Linear(100, n_outputs, nobias=True)

    def __call__(self, X):
        # -> Input
        self.I = Variable(X)

        # -> 14*14*16
        self.conv1_hidden = self.conv1(self.I)
        self.relu1_hidden = F.relu(self.conv1_hidden)
        self.maxpool1_hidden = F.max_pooling_2d(self.relu1_hidden, 2)

        # -> 5*5*32
        self.conv2_hidden = self.conv2(self.maxpool1_hidden)
        self.relu2_hidden = F.relu(self.conv2_hidden)
        self.maxpool2_hidden = F.max_pooling_2d(self.relu2_hidden, 2)

        # -> 1*1*64
        self.conv3_hidden = self.conv3(self.maxpool2_hidden)
        self.relu3_hidden = F.relu(self.conv3_hidden)

        # -> 100
        self.l4_hidden = self.l4(self.relu3_hidden)
        self.relu4_hidden = F.relu(self.l4_hidden)

        # -> n_outputs
        self.pred = self.l5(self.relu4_hidden)

        return self.pred


model = Model1(3, 1)
inp = np.arange(1 * 3 * 30 * 30, dtype=np.float32).reshape((1, 3, 30, 30))
model_pred = model(inp)
out = F.sum(model_pred)

out.backward(retain_grad=True)
print(type(model.pred.grad))
print(type(model.I.grad))
```

Output 4

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

となっており，質問者のコードにおいてもbackward(retain_grad=True)は正しく動作しております．

貴方のissueで生じた動作は，同じくメモリの効率化によって生じたものです．

すごく短く言えば，backward(retain_grad=True)は「ライフタイムが切れた，誰からも参照されていないVariableについてはgradやinputを保存しない」という動作をします．

[追記]
基本的にはVariableのライフタイムについて気にする必要は無いはずです．
もしデバッグ用に，すでに実装されているFunctionの一時的なVariableにアクセスがしたい場合には，上記の方法でgradを取り出すことができます．

Comment: この場合、別に自分で自己回答する Q&A を作成してそこへのリンクをコメントする形や、自分の回答の末尾に追記編集する形にすることができます。編集は回答下の「編集」から自由に行えます。回答の間で会話が始まると後から読みにくいため、お好みの形にまとめて頂けると幸いです。お手数ですがどうぞよろしくお願いいたします<(_ _)>